# How do I update a DocumentDb document?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have a Category->Question relationship in my DocumentDb. The Category documents contain a string-reference to the Questions id. When I add a question, I want to update the list of strings referenced in a Category. This is my code:

```
    public async Task<string> CreateQuestion(Question question, string categoryId)
    {
        var res = await client.CreateDocumentAsync(collectionLink, question);
        var category = GetCategory(categoryId);
        if (category.Questions == null) {
            category.Questions = new List<string>();
        }
        category.Questions.Add(categoryId);
        await client.ReplaceDocumentAsync(category.SelfLink, category);
        return res.Resource.Id;
    }
```

Everything returns without error, but the category-document is not updated with the list of questions.

What am I missing?

Comment: I have now also tried using ``UpsertDocumentAsync`` with no difference in outcome.

Comment: I see no obvious error; is it possible that the value of category.SelfLink might be wrong ? It would be at least a possible cause for the symptom...

Comment: Using fiddler I see that it's not sending the updated category object at all. It's like I do nothing with it between retrieving it and trying to update it. Strange!

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer - sort of - in this old GitHub issue: https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-dotnet/issues/7

I made my classes inherit from `Resource` instead of `Document` and now it works as expected.